# How to request publish permissions using Facebook's Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Without using any UI/Button, how to ask for publish permissions for Facebook app using Facebook's Android SDK? I'm currently using this code but it registers the callback twice giving me duplicate results. What is the correct way to ask for publish permissions?

```
    List<String> basicPermissions = Arrays.asList("user_friends", "user_games_activity");
    List<String> publishPermissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, basicPermissions);
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, publishPermissions);

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResults) {

                    new GraphRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "/{my-app-id}/scores",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                    // my code
                                }
                            }
                    ).executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                    Log.e("dd","facebook login canceled");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {



                    Log.e("dd", "facebook login failed error");

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to FB, you shouldn't request the publish permissions until after the user has successfully returned from the read permissions request. So you'd have to change it to something like so:

```
private boolean publishPermissionsRequested = false;
private LoginResult readResultSuccess;

private void loginWithFacebook(){
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResults) {
                if(!publishPermissionsRequested){
                    publishPermissionsRequested = true;
                    readResultSuccess = loginResults;

                    LoginManager.getInstance()
                            .logInWithPublishPermissions(this, publishPermissions);

                    return;
               }

               onFacebookLoginSuccessful(loginResults);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() { 
                if(publishPermissionsRequested && readResultSuccess != null)
                    onFacebookLoginSuccessful(readResultSuccess);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) { { 
                if(publishPermissionsRequested && readResultSuccess != null)
                    onFacebookLoginSuccessful(readResultSuccess);
            }
        });

    LoginManager.getInstance()
            .logInWithReadPermissions(this, basicPermissions);
}

private void onFacebookLoginSuccessful(LoginResult loginResults){
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/{my-app-id}/scores",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                 public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                      // Your code
                 }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

This way it will still continue as a success if they accept the read permissions but reject (or fail out of) the publish permissions request.

Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.